# How do you find out which boot loader your using in damn small linux distribution

Tags: boot-loader

Im trying to figure out which boot loader  my damn small linux distribution is using which can be either LILO or GRUB. This list all the installed packages http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/packages.html .Both the LILO and GRUB folders are available .

```
grub-install -v
grub-install (GNU GRUB 0.91)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, we can't know, we don't have access to your machine! Please [edit] your question and add a screenshot of your bootloader screen. Usually, the name of the bootloader is mentioned right there.

Comment: @terdon I uploaded the photo

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot, Damn Small Linux (DSL) is running from a **Live CD** in a virtual machine. So the boot loader is most likely **ISOLINUX**.

According to [this readme text file](http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/current/1-readme_first.txt), there are four types of DSL.

> dsl-<version>.iso: the standard isolinux version, which is used for
>   liveCD,  frugal, or traditional harddrive install.
>
> dsl-<version>-syslinux.iso: boots using syslinux instead of isolinux, 
>   used for some very old hardware that is no longer supported by
>   isolinux.   Use syslinux version if booting fails with the standard
>   iso.
>
> dsl-<version>-embedded.zip: comes with qemu, for running inside of a
>   host  Windows or Linux system.
>
> dsl-<version>-vmx.zip:  a virtual machine that will run in VMware or 
>   VMware player.

User would usually download the standard `dsl-<version>.iso`, which OP probably did. If `dsl-<version>-syslinux.iso` was downloaded, the boot loader would be Syslinux instead. User can tell by which type of DSL has been downloaded.

In case DSL is installed on a hard disk, the boot loader could be either LILO or GRUB. However, it has been mentioned in [this how-to](http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/current/documentation/FrugalHowto.pdf) (PDF document) that the default boot loader is LILO.

In case DSL is installed on a USB flash drive, the boot loader can be either GRUB or Syslinux. For more information, you can visit [this wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20171113180300/http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/install_to_usb_from_within_linux.html) (via web archive).

> Both the LILO and GRUB folders are available

That was the incorrect place. For a Live CD, user should check *inside the ISO image file* itself. The easiest way is to open the ISO image file in an archive manager.

[image: viewing inside DSL 4.4.10 ISO image file in an archive manager]

Inside the ISO image file, look into `/boot/isolinux` directory for the boot loader configuration files. The `isolinux.cfg` file contains settings that could be used in the `boot: _` prompt. Then again, when DSL (or any distro) has been installed to a hard disk, user should check the content of `/boot` directory on the local disk instead. If GRUB2 is used, `/boot/grub` directory will exist.

**TL;DR** A Live CD traditionally uses ISOLINUX as the boot loader. Open the ISO image file and check what files are found inside.